# Symmetric matrix singular iff zero on diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I'm sanity-checking a proof I have that a symmetric matrix is singular iff it has a zero on the diagonal. I don't think this proof is right, but I can't find out why.

Forward direction, $S \text{ is singular} \Rightarrow \exists i :  S_{ii} = 0$.
$$
\begin{align*}
S \text{ is singular} && \text{given} \\
\exists i : \lambda_i & = 0 && \text{all singular matrices have a 0 eigenvalue} \\
S & = Q \Lambda Q^T && \text{eigendecomposition (diagonalizable because symmetric)} \\
S_{ii} & = \lambda_i q_i^{\top}q_i \\
S_{ii} & = 0 && \blacksquare
\end{align*}
$$
Backward direction $\exists i : S_{ii} = 0 \Rightarrow S \text{ is singular}$
$$
\begin{align*}
\exists i : S_{ii} & = 0 && \text{given} \\
S & = Q \Lambda Q^T && \text{eigendecomposition} \\
S_{ii} & = \lambda_i q_i^{\top} q_i = 0 \\
\lambda_i & = 0 && q_i \neq 0 \text{ because it's an eigenvector} \\
S & \text{ is singular} && \text{any 0 eigenvalue means singular } \blacksquare
\end{align*}
$$

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: A matrix with all entries being the same is clearly singular and symmetric.

Comment: @MooS Right, that's a good counterexample. Do you also happen to see a flaw in the logic of my proof?

Comment: In both directions (both are false) you are wrong when you compute $S_{ii}$.

Comment: @MooS Oh duh, thank you!